# How to create pdf files using zend frame work?

Tags: zend-framework, pdf, zend-pdf

Can any body knows how to create pdf files using zend frame work?
please let me know ....

advance in thanks,
Azhar Ahammed.

Answer (score 2):

did you try reading through Zend's documentation?
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.create.html